# Keep unpressed state of a child view from a ListView item which is pressed

Tags: android, listview, view, state

I have a ListView which contains items with an ImageView in each item. This ImageView has a OnClickListener. I set a XML background to set drawables for pressed and normal states.
The onItemClick on the ListView and onClick on the ImageView are fired as expected, but the thing is when I click on the item (not on the ImageView), it also show the pressed state on the ImageView. I want to keep the normal state on the ImageView in this case...

I tried duplicateParentState="false", played with the focus, etc. I didn't find the solution yet.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Thank you,
Erwan

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding clickable attribut to inner items of my listview item. After that listview item not share pressed state with views, which are clickable.

Just add:

```
   android:clickable="true"
```

(tested on 4.1)

Hope this could help to someone, I personally could not find so simple solution.

Comment: you must set all your prarent viewgroup with "android:clickable="true""

Answer (score 0):

I've found in some of my experiments with ListView that only one element in the listitem can support an onClickListener - I haven't found any documentation that supports this idea though.

e.g if you list item contained a checkbox, or a ratingbar then I wouldn't be able to fire an onClick event for the listitem it is contained within

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I have only one view in my item which has a click listener. The onClickListener and onItemClickListener are fired when needed. The problem is just when I press the item, the ImageView drawable also changes to the pressed state instead of staying in the normal state.

Comment: Do you have the getView() implementation handy? Could you post the source.

Comment: I made the getView myself indeed. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to post the source, although I know it may be clearer... :/
I know I can fix it by implementing OnTouchListener, but it's heavy for a such little UI thing like that...